# Selecting one spinner updates the adapter of another spinner. Can I select both spinners programmatically?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I have two Spinners in an activity, `aSpinner` and `bSpinner`. The contents of the second spinner are dependent upon the selection of the first spinner. Currently, the onItemSelected method sets the adapter for the second spinner based on the first spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    if (parent == aSpinner) {
        buildAdapterForSpinner(bSpinner, getSpinnerOptions(pos));
        // Do something
    } else if (parent == bSpinner) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I want to programmatically select options on both of these spinners.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    aSpinner.setSelection(1, true);
    bSpinner.setSelection(1, true);
}
```

The first selection works just fine, but the second selection has no effect. However, if I introduce a 50ms delay before the second selection, everything behaves the way I want it to.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    aSpinner.setSelection(1, true);
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> bSpinner.setSelection(1, true), 50);
}
```

My suspicion is that onItemSelected is not being called immediately after the first spinner selection, therefore the second spinner has no adapter and cannot make a selection.

Using a hardcoded delay like this seems hacky. Is there a better way for me to make both of these selections without having to use a delay?

Comment: Tried on emulator, everything works perfectly for me without handlers. Can you post your full code?

Comment: post full code, this should work normally as well without handlers and delay